# meaning: all in on it together

Tags: prepositions

Again *Good Luck Charlie*.

PJ has lost his baby sibling Charlie, temporarily. He doesn't know what to do. He also thinks his parents will be disappointed knowing it. He regrets and feels guilty. He says,

> Why do I always mess up things?

His sister Teddy comforts him, saying,

> This one, we're all *on it* together.

Teddy sounds like they want to share the blame together.

I didn't hear it clearly. It could be more likely "on it", but "in it" or "in on it" could be possible too.

What's the preposition in your opinion? What does it mean?

Comment: The usual expression would be _all in it together_, meaning that they were all involved in what had happened and so, as you say, share the blame.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure you've got the quote correctly.

- "In it together" usually means that other people are sharing the experience with you. It is a reassuring, comforting expression that means you are not alone in going through something. Aside from this idiomatic usage, it could also be used where "in" is the correct preposition for whatever "it" refers back to - for example, "we are in the car together".
- "In on it together" usually means that you jointly planned or orchestrated something with others. In some contexts, it can imply a degree of secrecy or conspiracy.
- "On it together" isn't really an idiom, but could be grammatically correct if "on" is the correct preposition for whatever you are speaking about - for example, "we were on the boat trip together". "It" could refer to the previously mentioned boat trip.

In your example, it sounds like it should be "in it together", as the conversation previously refers to "a mess", and we speak about being "in" a mess.